Decompress a .csv.gz file
I'm trying to decompress multiple .csv.gz files and I can't seem to find somewhere where it's explained clearly.
I've never seen this double format and from what I understood I need a different method for each.
Could you help ?
Thank you !

Treat it as a .gz file, and the decompressed result as a .csv (which isn't a compression format).

gunzip foo.csv.gz
Then you will have a CSV file, foo.csv, that you can read directly as text, or import into any spreadsheet program.

read.csv(gzfile(yourfile),header = T, sep = ",")


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
